# Sliding images with finger touch in a web page

Tags: javascript, mobile

We routinely slide images with the finger in smartphone apps. But is it possible to get the same thing in a normal web page viewed on a smartphone?

Comment: What do you mean with 'slide'? Do you mean that it should scroll? Also, could you name one or more popular apps that demonstrate how this would work?

Comment: Yes, you should use `touchmove` event. But what have you tried?

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Puvq4/2/) what you meant? (Open in your mobile browser as http://jsfiddle.net/Puvq4/2/show/ to see the full version).

Comment: Javascript supports touch events. So YES.